# Using nested ng-repeat with dynamic ng-model as object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Okay let me be honest as i am a beginner in angular i am not sure how to frame this question i will try my best to explain this question.

Pic 1 : 
[image]

As you see in the above pic i have a situation where I have a list of classes, and each class will have no of sections under it. you can see a blue button on each row on clicking which i need to know which 'section' was selected.

This is the problem statement.

Now here is the HTML I have for this

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Syllabus</th>
      <th>{{phrase.className}}</th>
      <th>Select Section</th>
      <th>{{phrase.Operations}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="class in classes| filter:searchText">
      <td id="syl">
        <span ng-repeat="(sid, syllabi)  in syllabus" ng-if="sid == class.classAcademicYear">
            {{ syllabi.yearTitle}}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td id="cls">{{class.className}}</td>
      <td id="sec">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control" name="student_section" ng-model="selectedSection">
             <option ng-selected='class.sections[$index].id' ng-repeat="(key, section) in class.sections" value="{{section.id}}">{{section.sectionName}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="vew">
        <button ng-click="edit(class.id)" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat" title="{{phrase.ReadSchedule}}" tooltip><i class="fa fa-fw fa-th-list"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="!classes.length">
      <td class="noTableData" colspan="3">{{phrase.NoClasses}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here we see a nseted ng-repeat where i am creating table rows based on the list of classes, now this class object also holds the section object inside as you can see inner ng-repeat uses that classes.sections to iterate the options

Now the classes json object is as shown below

```
[{
  "id": 11,
  "className": "Class-1 (STATE)",
  "classAcademicYear": 2,
  "classSubjects": "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\"]",
  "dormitoryId": null,
  "sections": [{
    "id": 11,
    "sectionName": "Section -1 (STATE)",
    "sectionTitle": "section title -1",
    "classId": 11,
    "teacherId": "[\"10\",\"11\",\"12\",\"13\",\"14\",\"15\"]"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 12,
  "className": "Class-2",
  "classAcademicYear": 2,
  "classSubjects": "[\"0\"]",
  "dormitoryId": null,
  "sections": [{
    "id": 12,
    "sectionName": "Section -1",
    "sectionTitle": "section title -1",
    "classId": 12,
    "teacherId": "[\"0\"]"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 13,
  "className": "Class-3",
  "classAcademicYear": 2,
  "classSubjects": "[\"0\"]",
  "dormitoryId": null,
  "sections": [{
    "id": 13,
    "sectionName": "Section -1",
    "sectionTitle": "section title -1",
    "classId": 13,
    "teacherId": "[\"0\"]"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 14,
  "className": "Class-4",
  "classAcademicYear": 2,
  "classSubjects": "[\"0\"]",
  "dormitoryId": null,
  "sections": [{
    "id": 14,
    "sectionName": "Section -1",
    "sectionTitle": "section title -1",
    "classId": 14,
    "teacherId": "[\"0\"]"
  }]
}]
```

What I am trying to do is set a ng-model for the inner select dropdown element that is dynamic , something like below so that every time the section is selected i can set the blue button action to whatever section id is.

> ng-model="selectedSection[class.id]"

which is not working.

I know this might not be sufficient information but if some one is interested to help solve me this i can share further details.

Comment: It will be much better if you give a working code (say jsbin or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

For checking what ng-repeat line was selected you should send values $index  and $parent.$index (if you have nested ng-repeat).

```
<button ng-click="edit($index, $parent.$index)" type="button">
```

Does it help?

Comment: $parent.$index is undefined! & can we access $index of the 2nd ng-repeat out of it, I mean button has to be within the ng-repear isnt't

Comment: of course, your ng-click attribute with $index, $parent.$index should be inside the second loop.

Comment: Why would i place the button inside options loop ? Can u take a look at the HTML once more

Comment: Let's create a working example on jsbin. And I will try to help.